# Removing a method call from inside a static lib(.a) without recompiling

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm using a static lib thats giving me a warning when uploading my binary for review by apple.

The method in the static lib that causes the warning(non-public selectors) is never called by me, its corresponding .h is deleted from my proj, but warning still persists.

Given that I know the method name causing the problem, is there a way for me to open/edit this  .a and comment/delete the offending piece of code and then use the modified .a in my project.

I don't have access to the .a source to recompile it, and its very old and the creator of it has no contact details for me to track down.

Many Thanks,
-Cake

Comment: What's the library? Which private API is it using?

Comment: No private api was used. He created a method called urlEncodedString which shares the same name as a private API so it gets a false positive. The method is not being used by the app at all so I want to remove it.

Comment: You won't be able to touch anything in an already compiled library. Either remove the entire thing, find the source and modify, or risk Apple rejecting it.

Comment: Well if Apple are able to scan/parse through it and find the method name being called.. surely there is a way for us to scan through a it to look for the method name being called.

Comment: As for all the mofo's who go through my apps and remove my attempts at copyright protection.... I'd imagine there must be away.

Comment: Since you're keeping a name (or maybe even a download link) of this library such a secret it doesn't look like you're trying to get in touch with the author. Don't want to accuse you of anything, don't get me wrong. But it's possible that you'll find the author here on SO and your problems can be solved the easy way. :) +1: it is an interesting question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution: Open the .a file in a hex editor and change all instances of the name. Leave the function name the same length so that offsets in the file don't change, just change a letter or something like that. I did a quick test, adding a dummy function to a subproject we're building as a static library then tweaking the function name in the .a file (there were five instances, for what that's worth) and everything built okay. I don't see any reason it wouldn't pass the App Store check after that.

I'm really surprised the function was still there in the final build, though—I thought Dead Code Stripping was supposed to clean out any unused code. Huh.

Comment: If its used internally by the library, it isn't considered "dead code".

Comment: In my test case, I'd made a new function that wasn't used anywhere. Dead code stripping was enabled, but the function wasn't removed. So.

Comment: Because - I assume - you haven't added -ffunction-sections and -Wl,--gc-sections to your compiler flags.

Answer (score 2):

http://opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-809/

I don't presume to get your bounty, because I haven't provided an easy solution. But yes, it in theory is possible. You have your work cut out for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions, depending on your lib and project.

In your build settings :

1. Enable "**dead code stripping**" if possible : If the method is never used (even internally), the symbol will be deleted.
2. Use "**Unexported symbol file**" : Simply add the symbol into a file and it will be removed from the binary. This will work even if the symbol is used internally.
3. Enable "**Deployment Postprocessing**" and "**Strip Linked Product**" with "**Strip Style**" set to "**All symbol**"
4. (Not sure) Use "**Symbols Hidden by Default**". This is related to the code generation and should not affect linking, but just in case everything above failed...

Answer (score 0):

No need to hack the binary files. Just turn off the compiler's "unused selectors" warning: -fno-unused-selectors.